# R Shiny isolate() returns a date as an integer

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create an input form that adds a row to an existing dataframe.
I used the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840393/r-shiny-add-values-to-a-dataframe-and-save-them).

The problem I am having is that I have two date input types that are transformed to integer with this code.

Here is some sample data:

```
x_df <- data.frame(title = character(1), start = character(1), end = character(1))
x$title <- "Test1"
x$start <- as.Date("2017-12-16")
x$end <- as.Date("2017-12-17")
```

And my code:

```
library(shiny)

runApp(
list(
ui = fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(

      selectInput("Employee", "Choose an employee:",
                  choices_employee),

      dateInput("Date_from", "From:", format = "yyyy/mm/dd"),

      dateInput("Datum_until", "Until:", format = "yyyy/mm/dd"),

      actionButton("Add", "Add")

    )
  )
),

server = function(input, output) {

  values <- reactiveValues()
  values$df <- x_df
  addData <- observe({

    # your action button condition
    if(input$Add > 0) {
      # create the new line to be added from your inputs
      newLine <- isolate(c(input$Employee, input$Date_from, input$Date_until))
      # update your data
      # note the unlist of newLine, this prevents a bothersome warning message that the rbind will return regarding rownames because of using isolate.
      values$df <- isolate(rbind(as.matrix(values$df), unlist(newLine)))
      x_df <<- as.data.frame(values$df)
    }
  })

}
)
)
```

I think it's `isolate()` that is transforming the date into an integer, anyone knows how I can make this work? Any help is greatly appreciated. If my question is not clear enough please let me know and I will try my best to improve it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code in the OP's post is not working.  So, it is changed to get the output using `renderDataTable` from `DT` package.  Also, changed the `as.matrix` and `unlist` which could change the column type when there are mixed class columns.  For e.g.

```
unlist(as.list(Sys.Date() + 0:5))
#[1] 17537 17538 17539 17540 17541 17542
```

The corrected code is below

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(
     
      
      sidebarLayout(
        
        sidebarPanel(
          
          selectInput("Employee", "Choose an employee:",
                      choices_employee),
          
          dateInput("Date_from", "From:", format = "yyyy/mm/dd"),
          
          dateInput("Date_until", "Until:", format = "yyyy/mm/dd"),
          
          actionButton("Add", "Add")
          
        ),
        mainPanel(
          dataTableOutput("table")
        )
      )
      
    
    ),
    
    server = function(input, output) {
      
      values <- reactiveValues()
      values$df <- x_df
      addData <- observe({
        
       
        if(input$Add > 0) {
          # create the new line to be added from your inputs
          newLine <- isolate(data.frame(title = input$Employee, start = as.Date(input$Date_from),
                                          end = as.Date(input$Date_until), stringsAsFactors= FALSE))
          
          values$df <- isolate(rbind(values$df, newLine))
         
          
        }
      })
      
      output$table <- renderDataTable({values$df })
      
    }
  )
)
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
x_df <- data.frame(title = character(1), start = character(1), end = character(1))
x_df$title <- "Test1"
x_df$start <- as.Date("2017-12-16")
x_df$end <- as.Date("2017-12-17")
choices_employee = LETTERS[1:5]
```